# Calling same ViewController Again and Again

Tags: objective-c

I am having a UITableView Class.I am loading it again and again  by loading different Contents ever time on click of a cell.
say my class is TEstviewController and i am calling it again in dedSelectRowAtIndexPath
as by Allocating it and calling pushViewController..It is working very fine..I want to ASk is it the right Way ? 
The Problem is i Don't now how many subcategory a Main category has.and further a subcategory has.i have to dig deep till last subcategory....i can't fix the limit of view's

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're releasing every new view as soon as you push it onto the navigation stack you should be fine. There's nothing wrong with instantiating multiple copies of the same object.